# Limit the access depending on URL on ALB with Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

I have `ECS(Fargate)` which accept the `REST request` via `ALB`

Now I want to call this url from EventBridge every hour.
However I don't want to called this api from outside.

`main-lb-XXXXXX.ap-northeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com/api/`

And other urls should be called from the outside.

`main-lb-XXXXXX.ap-northeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com/`(other than api)

So,What I wan to do is

1. `main-lb-XXXXXX.ap-northeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com/api/` should be accessed from EventBridge only.
2. `main-lb-XXXXXX.ap-northeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com/` (other than /api) should be accessed from outside.

This settings can be done??

`ResourcePolicy` could be used for `ALB`?

Should I use `SecurityGroup` or something?

Comment: Security Groups can't limit access for different URL paths. You could probably do what you want by attaching a WAF to the load balancer and creating some custom WAF rules.

Comment: @MarkB I think in theory could use SGs for this restriction, but you would need two load balancer and 2 DNS names. In the public load balancer, black hole the /api route to return a 4XX and in the other only route /api and apply your SG restricts on the 2nd ALB.

Comment: ＠Jordanm Thanks for your help and good information for SG. In mycase, I will try to use WAF, but your advice also helps.